# Azure Database -> Excel Query

Tags: excel, azure-sql-database

I have a query being executed in a Azure server periodically and I need to add some code to it, so it can save some data from Tables/Views to a Excel file during the execution.
I have implemented some code like this on other databases (non-Azures), but executing the same code in Azure gives me messages like "Azure doesn't support" some of the tools I used.
What should I use to do this? I just got to save some Tables data to specific sheets in Excel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In case if the requirement is specific to Excel file creation ; you can use a logic app to query database from Azure SQL database and generate Excel file based on the below link:
`https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/d365fortechies/posts/logic-app-for-azure-sql-db-to-azure-file-storage-workflow`

Note: You can select Excel file generation for Logic app rather than CSV mentioned in the above example or generate an CSV file and then convert into Excel

Comment: Azure data factory till now doesn't support Excel as a sink else that would have been a pretty easy option .
So you would have to use Logic app or other ETL tools like SSIS to read data from Azure SQL database and generate an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Since `OPENDATASOURCE` is not supported in Azure SQL. You also can use other ETL tools to save some data from Tables/Views to a Excel.

Such as [Azure data factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/):

> Using Copy activity in Azure data factory, you can query from table, execute your sql query and execute stored procudure then convert to a Excel file. There are multiple destinations for you to choose to store this excel, cloud or local server.